# Problems converting XML to JSON using XSLT

Tags: xml, json, xslt

I am trying to convert an XML to JSON using XSLT. Following are my XML and XSLT code.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Subrayana kathe</title>
        <artist>Subba</artist>
        <country>India</country>
        <price>30</price>
        <year>1986</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      {
"catalog":[
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
         {"title":"
         <xsl:value-of select="title" />
         ",
"artist":"
         <xsl:value-of select="artist" />
         "},
      </xsl:for-each>
      ]
      }
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output of XSLT:

```
{
   "catalog":[
      {
         "title":"Empire Burlesque",
         "artist":"Bob Dylan"
      },
      {
         "title":"Subrayana kathe",
         "artist":"Subba"
      },(Problematic comma)
   ]
}
```

The problem is that there is an extra comma(',') at the end of the last object in the array. Is there a way to avoid that in XSLT ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only write the comma if there is another `cd` element in your xml.

So basically you have to wrap that comma in a `xsl:if` statement like this: `<xsl:if test="./following-sibling::cd">,</xsl:if>`

So your stylesheet will look something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      {
"catalog":[
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
         {"title":"
         <xsl:value-of select="title" />
         ",
"artist":"
         <xsl:value-of select="artist" />
         "}<xsl:if test="./following-sibling::cd">,</xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      ]
      }
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```